I don't see my images in Ckeditor 5 of Drupal 10
I use Drupal 10 and of course ckeditor5.
Unfortunately, I do not see the images or videos that I insert in the editor.
However, I see them well in the page.
In the editor, I only see that

When I select all the content otherwise nothing.
This is the first time that this happens to me and I do not know where it can come from.

Have a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed/issues/3272732
